# AWS describeLogGroups() does not return the log groups

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

AWS describeLogGroups() does not return the log groups.  Has anyone faced this?  If yes, how did you overcome?  Here's the code ...

```
import java.util.List;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.services.logs.AWSLogsClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.logs.model.DescribeLogGroupsResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.logs.model.LogGroup;

public class MyAWSLogGroups {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    AWSCredentials credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider().getCredentials();
    AWSLogsClient client = new AWSLogsClient(credentials);

    DescribeLogGroupsResult logGroupsResult = client.describeLogGroups();
    List<LogGroup> logGroups = logGroupsResult.getLogGroups();

    // why does logGroups.size() return 0 ?
    System.out.println("=> Number of Log Groups: " + logGroups.size()); 

    for (LogGroup lg : logGroups) {
      String logGroupName = lg.getLogGroupName();
      System.out.println(logGroupName);
    }

  }

}
```

This AWS CLI reveals the log groups ...

```
$ aws logs describe-log-groups
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but just had this problem myself. Are your Cloudfront Logs in the a region other than US East?

We're in US West. The Java SKD [defaults to us-east-1](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-region-selection.html) but you probably set your client default region a while ago.

Use the configureRegion inherited method on your Client to set to your location region. Get your Region Enum from the Regions [class documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/?com/amazonaws/regions/Regions.html).

For me the solution was something like this (using the example code from above):

```
import java.util.List;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.services.logs.AWSLogsClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.logs.model.DescribeLogGroupsResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.logs.model.LogGroup;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;

public class MyAWSLogGroups {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    AWSCredentials credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider().getCredentials();
    AWSLogsClient client = new AWSLogsClient(credentials);
    client.configureRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2);

    DescribeLogGroupsResult logGroupsResult = client.describeLogGroups();
    List<LogGroup> logGroups = logGroupsResult.getLogGroups();

    // why does logGroups.size() return 0 ?
    System.out.println("=> Number of Log Groups: " + logGroups.size()); 

    for (LogGroup lg : logGroups) {
      String logGroupName = lg.getLogGroupName();
      System.out.println(logGroupName);
    }

  }

}
```